# null pointer exceptions error is showing after executing junit test

Tags: cucumber-junit

I created a program in cucumber and facing issue like this.
pom.xml, step defination file , feature file and ruunable file are  created.

**In pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"        
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>CucumberTest1</groupId>
<artifactId>CucumberTest1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <dependencies>  
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> 
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId> 
<version>2.47.1</version> 
</dependency>

<dependency> 
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId> 
<version>1.0.2</version> 
<scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
<dependency> 
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId> 
<version>1.0.2</version> 
<scope>test</scope>
```

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>junit</groupId> 
<artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
<version>4.10</version> 
<scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

**Annotation.java*

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import cucumber.annotation.en.Given; 
import cucumber.annotation.en.Then; 
import cucumber.annotation.en.When; 

public class annotation { 
WebDriver driver = null; 
@Given("^I am on Facebook login page$") 
   public void goToFacebook()
 {               System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
  driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/"); 
  }

  @When("^I enter username as \"(.*)\"$") 
  public void enterUsername(String arg1) {   
  driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(arg1); 
  }

    @When ("^I enter password as \"(.*)\"$") 
    public void enterPassword(String arg1) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(arg1);
    driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_v")).click(); 
   } 

     @Then("^Login should fail$") 
     public void checkFail() {  
      if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(
      "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110")){ 
         System.out.println("Test1 Pass"); 
    }  else { 
     System.out.println("Test1 Failed"); 
   } 
  driver.close(); 
   }

 @Then("^Relogin option should be available$") 
  public void checkRelogin() { 
    if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(
     "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110")){ 
        System.out.println("Test2 Pass"); 
   } else { 
     System.out.println("Test2 Failed"); 
   } 
   driver.close(); 
   }
   }
```

**Ruunable class**

```
package Annotation; 

import org.junit.runner.RunWith; 
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber; 

@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}) 

public class runTest {   }
```

**featurefile**
      Feature: annotation 
      #This is how background can be used to eliminate duplicate steps

```
  Background: 
     User navigates to Facebook Given 
      I am on Facebook login page 

   #Scenario with AND 
    Scenario: 
     When I enter username as "TOM"
     And I enter password as "JERRY" 
     Then Login should fail 

    #Scenario with BUT 
  Scenario: 
    When I enter username as "TOM" 
    And I enter password as "JERRY" 
    Then Login should fail 
     But Relogin option should be available
```

**OUTPUT  ON CONSOLE**

```
Feature: annotation

     #This is how background can be used to eliminate duplicate steps
    Background:  [90m# Annotation\outline.feature:5[0m
     User navigates to Facebook Given 
      I am on Facebook login page


      #Scenario with AND
     Scenario:                         [90m#        Annotation\outline.feature:10[0m
 [90mWhen [0m[90mI enter username as "[0m[90m[1mTOM[0m[90m"[0m  [90m# annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m
[1A    [31mWhen [0m[31mI enter username as   "[0m[31m[1mTOM[0m[31m"[0m     [90m# annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m
  [31mjava.lang.NullPointerException
            at Annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:23)
        at ?.When I enter username as "TOM"(Annotation\outline.feature:11)
     [0m
[90mAnd [0m[90mI enter password as "[0m[90m[1mJERRY[0m[90m"[0m [90m# annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m
     [1A    [36mAnd [0m[36mI enter password as "[0m[36m[1mJERRY[0m[36m"[0m [90m# annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m
    [90mThen [0m[90mLogin should fail[0m          [90m# annotation.checkFail()[0m
 [1A    [36mThen [0m[36mLogin should fail[0m          [90m# annotation.checkFail()[0m

   #This is how background can be used to eliminate duplicate steps
   Background:  [90m# Annotation\outline.feature:5[0m
    User navigates to Facebook Given 
     I am on Facebook login page


    #Scenario with BUT
       Scenario:                                [90m#               Annotation\outline.feature:16[0m
[90mWhen [0m[90mI enter username as "[0m[90m[1mTOM[0m[90m"[0m         [90m# annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m
     [1A    [31mWhen [0m[31mI enter username as "[0m[31m[1mTOM[0m[31m"[0m         [90m# annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m
  [31mjava.lang.NullPointerException
    at Annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:23)
    at ?.When I enter username as "TOM"(Annotation\outline.feature:17)
  [0m
[90mAnd [0m[90mI enter password as "[0m[90m[1mJERRY[0m[90m"[0m        [90m# annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m
     [1A    [36mAnd [0m[36mI enter password as "[0m[36m[1mJERRY[0m[36m"[0m        [90m# annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m
     [90mThen [0m[90mLogin should fail[0m                 [90m# an notation.checkFail()[0m
  [1A    [36mThen [0m[36mLogin should fail[0m [90m# annotation.checkFail()[0m
   [90mBut [0m[90mRelogin option should be available[0m [90m# annotation.checkRelogin()[0m
    [1A    [36mBut [0m[36mRelogin option should be available[0m [90m# annotation.checkRelogin()[0m

      java.lang.NullPointerException
       at Annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:23)
        at ?.When I enter username as "TOM"(Annotation\outline.feature:11)

       java.lang.NullPointerException
         at Annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:23)
       at ?.When I enter username as "TOM"(Annotation\outline.feature:17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change background part of your feature file as below

```
Background: User navigates to Facebook
Given I am on Facebook login page
```

Currently it is like,

```
Background: 
User navigates to Facebook Given
I am on Facebook login page
```

Please update me whether its solved issue or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\geckodriver.exe");

Hope this solves the issue!

Comment: i added this but its not working I think their is issue with junit and selenium